# Return nested array with Ruby Grape in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, grape-api

I have successfully built an api as you can see [here](https://www.soledadmemorial.com/api/v1/plaques) and the code is below.  I need to list the objects as a nested array and not an array of objects, but I cannot figure it out.

**api/v1/plaques.rb**

```
module API  
    module V1
      class Plaques < Grape::API
        include API::V1::Defaults

        resource :plaques do
          desc 'Return all Plaques'
          get '', root: :plaques do
            Plaque.all
          end

          desc 'Return a Plaque'
          params do
            requires :id, type: String, desc: 'ID of Plaque'
          end
          get ':id', root: 'plaque' do
            Plaque.where(id: permitted_params[:id]).first!
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

What I'm getting:

```
[
    {
    "veteran_first": "Alexis",
     ...
    }
]
```

What I need:

```
 "items" =  [
        {
        "veteran_first": "Alexis",
         ...
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Not really understood what you mean by the last piece of code. Do you want JSON like `{ "items": [ {}, {}, ... ] }`?

Comment: @user3309314 sorry, I wrote the post a little fast- yes that is what I am looking for.

Comment: Returning `{ items: Plaque.all }` does what you want?

Comment: @user3309314 Worked like a charm!!  Please create the answer so I can except.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code returns JSON you want:

```
get '', root: :plaques do
  { items: Plaque.all }
end
```